# What is the Halacha related to whether or not to confess your crime prior to an investigation?

Tags: halacha, criminal-procedure

If you have committed a crime such as fraud and an investigation is imminent, is there any halachic guidance on whether or not to come forward to the victim?

Comment: Is the alternative lying? Why would that be better?

Comment: Wouldn't some types of fraud fall under the same category as stealing something, in which case, you have to pay double? And isn't the double penalty only if they catch you, not if you return the item?

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe what the OP is asking is should the person who committed the crime come forward and confess, or can he wait until he is charged with committing the crime or people forget about the whole thing...

Comment: @ezra maybe. Maybe not. this is why one sentence posts are so bad.

Comment: @DoubleAA agreed. :)

Comment: Are you asking how to balance self-accusation with honesty? Editing your question to give more background and explicitly call out the tradeoffs you see would make it easier to answer

Comment: Interestingly, the Talmud deals with cases that already reach the court.  However, I do not recall (**besides the explicit Mitzvah of "והשיב את הגזילה" to return the steal**) a ruling to resolve a case **before** it reaches the court. Moreover, as one is not required to pay any extras, not directly inflicted by the misdeed, **there's no practical difference in repaying before of after the trial**. Keep in mind that in Torah there's no "State prosecution" of the civil law, only the claimant can file a claim, not "the State".

Comment: Are you asking about the halacha requiring teshuvah and the secular courts investigating? If one has done something wrong, the halacha requires teshuvah and returning any money owed as a result.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=המודה%20בקנס%20פטור&filters=Talmud|Halakhah/Mishneh%20Torah&var=1&sort=c&lang=en המודה בקנס פטור one whoadmits he is liable to pay a fine, even ifwitnesses come afterward and testify that he is liable to pay it. The mishna teaches that he is nevertheless exempt,due to his admission.